Get the result of a Task<T> to handle its completion
I'm making my way through async programming in C#.
I often await a Task<T> that does some stuff that doesn't necessarily return a value (uploading a file on cloud or updating a line in a database)
an example is:
public async Task UploadFileAsync(string filePath, string destBlobFolder)
{
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(filePath, dest);
}

In the caller method I often do
var upload = await UploadFileAsync(file, destination)
but I started having the necessity to understand if the task came to completion or not so I am now using this very odd way of capturing a return string to check if the async method is completed or not:
public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(string filePath, string destBlobFolder)
{
    try
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fs, Options);
        return "complete";
    }
    catch (exception ex) 
    {
        return "error";
    }
}

and in the caller method I check if the var upload == "error" or "complete".
I am pretty sure that this is not the way to work so I was looking for a more elegant way of doing this.
(same scenario if I have to update a local SQLite database.)

There's no reason to write any extra code. await only proceeds if the asynchronous operation completes. The only thing the new version does is discard errors, making debugging and maintenance a lot harder

var upload = await UploadFileAsync(file, destination) <-- this won't compile if UploadFileAsync returns a Task (instead of a Task<T>) - so please clarify.

Exceptions are thrown if an asynchronous operation completes with an error. The best option, just like synchronous methods, is to just let the exceptions propagate to the point where you can handle them. With that catch{ return "error"; } you won't know if the upload failed due to incorrect credentials, throttling or using the wrong URL.

"I started having the necessity to understand if the task came to completion or not" -- Do you mean if the task came to successful completion or not?

if the task wasn't completed succsessfully, it'll throw an exception, as if it were "normal" method. So no difference between async and sync code.

I suspect you're using Azure BlobClient.UploadAsync. When that method fails it throws a RequestFailedException with the failing HTTP Status Code, service error code and the full API response.

If you are trying to introduce resilience, you may want to look into Polly, btw.

This has nothing to do with your method being async, but with how you transport information to your clients. Imagine a "normal" (=sync) method:
void DoSomething()
{
    if(/* errorcase 1 */
        return;
    if(/* error-case 2 */
        return;
    // do the actual stuff
    // ...
    return;
}

For a client it's completely unclear why the method returned, only that it did. So you need a way to transport errors to the client, which is usually by throwing an exception:
void DoSomething()
{
    if(/* errorcase 1 */
        throw new Exception("Case 1");
    if(/* error-case 2 */
        throw new Exception("Case 2");
    // do the actual stuff
    // ...
    return;
}

Now clients of your methods can easily examine if your method ran successfully. If no exception occurs, you can assume so.
The exact same applies to async code. If your async code doesn't throw, you can assume it ran to completion:
async Task DoSomething() { ... }
...
try
{
    await DoSomething();
    // if you reach here you know the task was successful
}
catch
{
    // we got an error, do whatever you want with it
}

You see there's no need for any "odd way of capturing a return string".

I think it may be worth mentioning that - if you are a bit negligent - you can end up creating an implicit async void which may be hidden / not obvious. And that would / could put an end to that convenient exception-propagation.

@Fildor haha, yeah, good catch. Yes, async void is pretty bad in most scenarios.
